# Printing the elements in multidemensional array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Help me to get correct result with this cplusplus program.
With this code I'm trying to print all the elements in array 'arr' with each inner array on it's own line.

Code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arr[3][4] = {
        {1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}
    };

    for (auto p = begin(arr); arr != end(arr); ++p) {
        for (auto q = begin(*p); q != end(*p); ++q) {

            cout << *q << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;

}
```

But when I execute this code the compiler shows me a bunch of memory addresses instead elements in array 'arr'. Did I do anything wrong with that code? And I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for programming, In case if you want to know.

Comment: There is no array 'arr' in the shown code. Please post real code, instead of fantasy code.

Comment: Typo. Change `ia != end(ia);` to `p != end(ia);`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry for that. I've just edited the code.

Comment: @songyuanyao OMG!!! Really I didn't see it! Such a clod I am!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
int ia[3][4] = {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                cout << ia[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Also your code works fine. I've done stupid with my code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just for Fun

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(void)
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3> const array = {{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}};

    if (array.begin() != array.end()) {
        auto itarray = array.begin();
        if (itarray->begin() != itarray->end()) { {
            auto itsubarray = itarray->begin();
            std::cout << *itsubarray;
            for (itsubarray = itsubarray + 1; itsubarray != itarray->end(); itsubarray++) {
                std::cout << " " << *itsubarray;
            } }
            for (itarray = itarray + 1; itarray != array.end(); itarray++) {
                for (int elem : *itarray) {
                    std::cout << " " << elem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you wish to use iterators:

```
#include <iterator>
using std::endl;
using std::begin;
using std::end;
using std::cout;


int main() {

    int arr[3][4] = { { 1,2,3,4 },{ 5,6,7,8 },{ 9,10,11,12 } };

    for (auto p = begin(arr); p != end(arr); ++p) {
        for (auto q = begin(*p); q != end(*p); ++q) {
            cout << *q << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The change is in the first for loop where you had `arr != end(arr)`, but you wanted `p != end(arr)`. And if you ever change the length of your array this loop will still work.